# Python Mysql insert working on Windows not on Linux

Tags: python, mysql-python

So I'm trying to get prices of crypto currencies via an API every N seconds and store them in a MySQL DB in Python 3. So far I have written this code.

```
import requests
import pymysql
import json
import threading


def addEthPrice():
    threading.Timer(11, addEthPrice).start()
    url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/'
    urlPrice = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR,GBP'
    login_data = dict(login='*', password='*')
    session = requests.session()
    r = session.post(urlPrice, data=login_data)
    print("Response Code: ", r, "\n")
    data = json.loads(r.content.decode())
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='*', db='eth')
    sql = "INSERT INTO price (date, ethGBP, ethUSD, ethEUR) VALUES(UTC_TIMESTAMP, %s, %s, %s)"
    params = (str(data['ETH']['GBP']),
              str(data['ETH']['USD']),
              str(data['ETH']['EUR']))
    try:
        with conn.cursor() as c:
            res = c.execute(sql, params)
            print(params)
            print("mysql response: ", res)
    finally:
        conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    addEthPrice()
```

Now this code runs fine on Windows and stores it in the DB here is the description of the table for Windows:

```
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| date   | timestamp     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ethGBP | decimal(12,8) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ethUSD | decimal(12,8) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ethEUR | decimal(12,8) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And here is the description for the Linux table:

```
+--------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+ 
| Field  | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       | 
+--------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| date   | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| ethGBP | decimal(12,8) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ethUSD | decimal(12,8) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ethEUR | decimal(12,8) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             | 
+--------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+                              
4 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

I have used the same syntax to create both the tables but the Linux one has added parameters.

Here's my question, When I run these script the data gets added fine to the WAMP MySQL but not to the Linux MySQL version, Why is this and how can I make it so it works on both.

```
Linux version 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Windows version MySQL5.7.14
```

Thanks.

Comment: How did you create the two tables?

Comment: create table price (date TIMESTAMP, ethGBP DECIMAL(12,8), ethUSD DECIMAL(12,8), ethEUR DECIMAL(12,8));

Comment: @Definity did you solve this. I am having a similar kind of issue.

Comment: I think It was that I didn't use backticks '`' in the insert method. But It was a long time ago so I'm guessing.